# Facebook login not working ionic native when emulating on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic-framework, simulator

While emulating the app I built on ionic on iOS simulator each time I log in with facebook native on the console on safari shows "There was a problem logging you in" message with no explanation.
If I test this on an android device it works fine. 
Im not able to test it on an iOS device because I don't have the developer membership.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-facebook-login',
 templateUrl: 'facebook-login.html'
})
export class FacebookLogin {
   userProfile: any = null;
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

   facebookLogin(){
   Facebook.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
      const facebookCredential = response.authResponse.accessToken;
      console.log(facebookCredential);
      this.userProfile = facebookCredential;
   }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
}
```

Any ideas?